# Splitting key values from stringlist

Tags: java, string, hashmap

okay so i have strings in a list like so:
`- String, boolean`
I basically want to grab a whole heap of these from a long string list (progressing downward) and throw them into a hashmap like the following so i can simply get the key (the string) and get the `boolean` value from the key.

The hashmap:
`public HashMap<String, Boolean> keyValues = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();`

thanks in advance folks.

PS: first time using stackoverflow, lets see how we go!

Comment: give a concrete list of data and show what you tried

Comment: okay i have data like the following: `types-enabled:
    - SIGN_COLOUR, false
    - SIGN_FORMAT, false
    - SIGN_ASHOP, false
    - SIGN_PSHOP, false` I have tried splitting the strings via the comma but i dont know how to actually grab the values.

Comment: `types-enabled:` is part of your input data ?

Comment: no this data is in a yaml configuration, `types-enabled` is simply a config path

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in one-line:

```
Pattern.compile("-")
    .splitAsStream(s)
        .map(string -> string.split(","))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k[0], v -> Boolean.valueOf(v[1])));
```

Where `s` is a string like this:

```
SIGN_COLOUR, false - SIGN_FORMAT, false - SIGN_ASHOP, false - SIGN_PSHOP, false
```

Answer (score 0):

That should be easy, isn't it?

```
public static Map<String,Boolean> toMap(List<String> l) {
    HashMap<String,Boolean> m = new HashMap<String,Boolean>();
    l.forEach((s) -> { String[] t=s.split(","); m.put(t[0], new Boolean(t[1])); });
    return m;
}
```